# High frequencies with FFT Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, filtering, fft

I'm doing some hybrid images, I get low frequencies with FFT applying a gaussian FT (image below) and doing the inverse FFT, so far I get the high frequencies by subtracting low frequencies to the original image, that way works but, is there any other way to do it?

I was thinking about applying the inverse gaussian in the frequency space but doesn't seem to work properly (or probably I'm not doing it the right way).

My code right now:

```
def generate_HF(image, im_low):
    im_gray_high = image - im_low
    im_gray_high = normalize(im_gray_high)
    return im_gray_high

human_fourier = fftpack.fft2(human_gray,fftshape)
cat_fourier = fftpack.fft2(cat_gray,fftshape)
gauss_fft = fftpack.fft2(gauss(9),fftshape)
cat_ifft = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(gauss_fft*cat_fourier))
hs=int(np.floor(50/2.))
cat_ifft_crop = normalize(cat_ifft[hs:cat_gray.shape[0]+hs, hs:cat_gray.shape[1]+hs])

human_ifft = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(gauss_fft*human_fourier))
hs=int(np.floor(50/2.))
human_ifft_crop = normalize(human_ifft[hs:human_gray.shape[0]+hs, hs:human_gray.shape[1]+hs])
cat_high = generate_HF(cat_gray, cat_ifft_crop)
hybrid = normalize(human_ifft_crop + cat_high)
```

Gaussian FT

[image: Gaussian FT]

Human LF

[image: Human LF]

Low and High frequency image

[image: Low and High frequency image]

Hybrid Image

[image: Hybrid Image]

Comment: Please post the images (not a link) and the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: To get high frequencies, take fourier transform of laplacian filter and multiply it with the fourier transform of image